# Video live streaming pause not working in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

In my app i am using video view for playing live streaming.Here is the code i am using to play the video.

```
try {
String http_url="rtsp://live.wmncdn.net/jiljillive/bbb19eae240ec100af921d511efc86a0.sdp";           
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        Uri video = Uri.parse(http_url);

        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I used **videoView.pause()** to pause the video.But unfortunately the video not paused when i click the button.

Please give the solution for pause the live video streaming.

Comment: pause() works fine for stopping the video, please post your full code

Answer (score 0):

you need to add these in your code for `pause` the video:

**LiveStreamFragment.java:**

```
private MediaController mediaController;

public class LiveStreamFragment extends Fragment implements OnPreparedListener,
        MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);


    @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mediaController.hide();
        }
  public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

 }
```